# Achar substring em mensagens de commits recentes

Tags: git, substring

Estou buscando uma *substring* nos commits mais recentes do meu repositório.

Utilizo o comando `git log -n1 --grep='${subString}'`.

Porém usando a flag `-n`só vou conseguir o último commit, que tecnicamente é o mais recente.
Ex:

```
commit 1a1a
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:30:40

       Esse commit tem a substring
```

Mas pode, e provavelmente vai, acontecer que exista mais de um commit feito recentemente, o que torna a flag `-n` ineficiente.

Ex:

```
commit 2b2b
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:40:02

       Esse commit não tem

commit 1a1a                             //Nesse caso, esse é o commit que eu quero.
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:30:40 

       Esse commit tem a substring
```

Há ainda os casos mais comuns, ondem exitam vários commits com a *substring* que estou buscando.

Ex:

```
commit 2b2b
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:40:02

       Esse commit não tem

commit 1a1a                             //Nesse caso, esse ainda é o commit que eu quero.
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:30:40 

       Esse commit tem a substring

commit 3c3c
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:20:11

       Esse commit também tem a substring

commit 4d4d                             
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 13:13:05 

       Esse commit também não tem
```

Considerando que os commits foram para o repositório remoto pelo mesmo comando `git push`, o que posso fazer para achar uma *substring* na mensagem do commit mais recente??

Comment: `git log -1 -p ":/subString"`? Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas o git log te permite buscar o ultimo commit contendo a mensagem, nesse caso `subString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o grep do terminal/shell/linux no lugar.

```
git log | grep --context=4 "TEXTO"
```

Um git log simples em conjunto com o grep do linux, pedindo para "agrupar" os resultados em 4 linhas para trás.

No meu teste local, exibiu três commits cujas mensagens descritivas possuíam a palavra procurada.