# GIT LOG: Como buscar um commit através de uma mensagem específica?

Tags: git, commit

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de usar o `git log` para listar os commits, filtrando através de uma mensagem específica.

Exemplo:

```
git commit -am "Correção do ícone de exclusão na listagem de usuários"
```

No caso acima, gostaria de aplicar um `git log` e ver apenas a lista de commits que tivessem a palavra "usuário".

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323641/achar-substring-em-mensagens-de-commits-recentes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Da [documentação do git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) podemos ver os parâmetros:

- `--all`: Lista os commits de todos os branch's, não apenas o que você está.
- `--grep=<pattern>` para restringir a busca para os commits cuja mensagem de log contenha o pattern exibido. Esse pattern segue as mesmas regras de expressão regular do comando grep.

Como no seu caso você deseja os commits apenas que contenham uma palavra, o comando fica:

```
git log --all --grep='usuário'
```